# Size in bytes of ellipsis function arguments

Tags: c++, c, printf, variadic-functions

I have a function :

```
static int myprintf(const char* fmt, ...)
```

I want to know the size in bytes of all myprintf arguments,if they were printed to buffer. 
I need allocate an array dynamically to which I can print the the arguments (using `sprinf` or `_vsprinf`)
For example in 32bit OS,for myprintf("%d %c",10,'a');
the size of myprintf arguments is 5.

I tried to implement it like:

```
va_list ap;

va_start(ap, fmt);

myArgSize(ap);
```

Can someone advise how to implement myArgSize.

I was told to try something like this

```
char c;
int len = ::_vsnprintf(&c, 1, fmt, ap);
```

It doesn`t work since more than one byte is written.
But probaly there is some workaround.

Thanks

Comment: You say "the size of myprintf arguments is 5." but if I understand what you're asking, no, it's 8 bytes on the stack. 4 for the int and 4 for, ehm, the other int. On a 32 bit system, all values in variadic functions are 4 bytes, except for floating point values. `float` and `double` are 8 bytes. And beware of the `long double`.

Comment: Are you interested in the number of characters used for the string representation, or the number of bytes used for the values themselves? These are totally different, e.g. a 4-byte integer might require anything from 1 to 10 characters when printed in decimal.

Comment: @MrLister: WTF are you smoking? `'a'` is a character, in C++, which by the very definition of `sizeof`, has `sizeof(char) == 1`. And on most machines, a `char` is 1 byte.

Comment: @unwind-thank you.you are right

Comment: @DeadMG sorry to burst your bubble, but this is in the content of a printf-like function (which was what I meant with "variadic"), where chars take up a whole integer when pushed on the stack. Try `printf("%d%d",'A','A');`

Comment: @MrLister: Isn't that *entirely* implementation dependent? For example, he could use a custom calling convention, or the compiler could inline the call. And I don't think he meant "The super-implementation-dependent size of the stack used to call the function", which is going to be bigger than the arguments anyway. The argument itself has a size of only one. The fact that any given implementation might wish to use more space than that on the stack is irrelevant. And I'm pretty sure that passing the wrong format specifier to `printf` is flat out UB, so your example means nothing.

Comment: @DeadMG Hm. Can you show me an example of such a custom calling convention for a variadic function? Which would presumably be one that doesn't use the varargs header? Or an example of a C compiler where `printf("%d%d",'A','A');` does not result in printing the decimal representation of 'A' (in ASCII, that would be 65) twice?

Comment: @DeadMG: Arguments are promoted before being passed through `...`, so `a` will be converted to `int`. That's the case in both languages. (C++11 5.2.2/7 if you want the gory details).

Comment: @unwind: A C question that involves `::func()` syntax? Not gonna happen. @MikeSeymour: Now that's a rational argument which might cloud the results. After all, I guess it depends on what you consider the "argument". @Yakov: Yes, and I had to edit back. Take a little more care next time.

Comment: @DeadMG: The "argument" is the value in the function call's argument list - that's well defined. If there's no matching parameter (i.e. if there's an ellipsis in the function declaration), then various conversions are applied, including integral promotions.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: In that case, the size of the "argument" is still 1, as it is a `char`.

Comment: @DeadMG: Yes, but the question is clearly asking about the size of the data in the `va_list`, despite the slightly imprecise use of the word "argument" in the title.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I'm not sure the question is clearly asking anything - I *think* what the OP ultimately wants is to know how many bytes would be written to the buffer. Even though most of the question is about the size of the arguments as passed on the stack, I think that's a red herring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though much of your question is about the size of the arguments passed to your triadic function, it seems to me that you're actually interested in  how big the output buffer needs to be.  Try something like the following:

```
va_list ap;

va_start(ap, fmt);

int len = ::vsnprintf( NULL, 0, fmt, ap);
if (len < 0) abort();

char* buffer = (char*) malloc( len + 1);
if (!buffer) abort();

::vsnprintf( buffer, len+1, fmt, ap);

va_end();
```

However, if your platform doesn't have a C99 standard compliant `vsnprintf()` (for example, MSVC) then you'll have to make some adjustments. For MSVC You could try passing in a buffer sized with a guess (maybe `strlen(fmt)+1 + (10 * number_of_percent_signs_in_fmt)` or just start with a size that should cover 99% of your cases - maybe `200`), and increase the guess until it works. Or you might try something like [the `snprintf()` family of functions by Holger Weiss](http://www.jhweiss.de/software/snprintf.html).

Answer (score 1):

Well ... The only information about the types and orders of the arguments is in the first argument; that's why it's required.

For a `printf()`-like function, you need to step through the formatting string, parse each `%`-code, and add the sizes of the corresponding types. It won't be trivial. Remember to handle things like `%hd` which expects a `short` rather than an `int`. Also, there are conversions that happen when values are passed to a variadic function.

Comment: Except his question is only tagged C++

Comment: @DeadMG Not now ... I don't think it was when I first found it, either.

Comment: Oh, he just edited it back again? I *hate* questioners who can't decide what language they're in. Edit: Someone *else* re-tagged it C. It's not in C. C doesn't have the `::func()` syntax. C++ does. So it *must* be written in C++.

Comment: @DeadMG Good point, didn't see those. I've edited out the C specific parts of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vasprintf` to do all the formatting into a buffer of the right size, which it will allocate (and you'll have to `free`).

Alternatively, `vsnprintf` can be used to get the length of the string `printf` would print:

```
int n = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, args);
```

This is because it returns the number of bytes it would print, if it had enough space. In this case it can't print anything, but returns the number anyway.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the sizeof(type_name) and travel through the all arguments using for loop,
the type_name is any of c datatype like int, float, long, etc..
Then add all bytes,